# How to access jpeg pixels of bytearray directly in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, jpeg

I'm trying to:

- load a jpeg through FileReference
- write the result to a bytearray
- extract the pixel data (and nothing else) directly from the bytearray

I've spent many hours looking for an AS3 class that can decode a jpeg object from raw binary data (such as from a bytearray), but to no avail (there is one [here](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1089) but it relies on Alchemy and a SWC, which isn't suitable).

Put simply, once I have the raw data in the byte array, I'm want to know how to discern the pixel data from the rest of the file.

I'm not interested in using the Loader class, or Bitmap's 'getPixels' function.

Comment: Do you just want the colors of each pixel?

Comment: No.  I want to adjust the color of certain pixels, and then write the bytearray back to the file system as a bytearray, without having to encode it (as it should already be jpeg encoded).

Comment: This class does the reverse of what you require. maybe you can adjust it? https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as

Comment: You need to decode the JPEG data in order to get the raw pixel values and then encode the bitmap with the JPEG algorithm again before saving. There's no concept of raw pixel data in the byte array of a JPEG file.

Comment: @LeeBurrows - thanks - I had tried that - but that class only accepts BitmapData as an arguement - whereas I only have a raw bytearray

Comment: @walkietokyo - yes, I know - I'm basically asking how to decode the bytearray such that I can access the pixel data.

Comment: @hunter The easiest way is using the `Loader` class and `BitmapData.getPixels` as described in the answer by Cay. Is there any particular reason why you would like to avoid that approach?

Comment: I meant adjust the JPEGEncoder class to do the reverse - input jpeg and output bitmapData.

Comment: Why is using Loader is such a no-no?

Comment: @LeeBurrows - I'm working on a [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) project.  I want to be able to make an exact clone of a jpeg; read the jpeg from file into a bytearray, adjusting certain pixel values to reflect a hidden message (aka steganography), and write the bytearray back to file without adjusting the rest of the file contents.  To do this using Loader and getPixels, I'd have to re-encode the jpeg, which (may) affect the hidden data, and would also affect the metadata (undesirable).  You're probably right about inversing that class, but it's probably beyond me.

Comment: @hunter if you want to hide your message in the pixel data, then you should probably look at a lossless image format, like PNG (some variants). Otherwise, you'll have to figure out a way to amend the data in the JPEG file without actually amending the pixels since this will unavoidably require decoding and encoding of the image. In your case is sounds simpler to write an encoded message in the metadata.

Comment: @walkietokyo - thanks - yes, I have managed to do this with PNG files, by encoding the information into the alpha channel (information is in hex, so the alpha-channel offset is only ever plus or minus 8, not discernable by the human eye).  I had imagined that encoding a lossy format like jpeg would result in data-loss, so yes, I'm trying to figure out how to modify to already-encoded jpeg.  It's hard than I had imagined :-P .  I might try your suggestion of modifying the exif-data, as it seems like the only option.

Answer (score 3):

you will notice that steganography relies on using a png file. The reason that you can't use the jpg file(easily) is that the encoding process removes the reliability of pixel data. Jpg files can be encoded in several ways, including CMYK and RGB but most often YCbCr. Jpg compression relies on Fourier transform, which will eliminate the pixel-level detail. Therefore you will not be able to use the same process on jpg and png,gif,bmp etc.

This is not to say that you cannot do it in a jpg file, but you need to change the approach, or account for loss of data at compressions stage (or save uncompressed).

Comment: I don't think that's explicitly true. If the pixel-data in the jpeg were to be manipulated *after* the encoding, then there would be no danger of the secret information being lost/mis-interpreted through compression.  If a jpeg file can be decoded/read in a consistent and deterministic, then I reason that there must be a way to decode the pixel data of an encoded jpeg, and edit it, without re-encoding the entire file.  True, it's complicated - but I think it's possible.  If jpeg files in fact can *not* be read/decoded consistently, then my assumption is wrong.

Comment: the issue is that there is no pixel data after encoding. The image is stored in blocks which use Discrete Cosine Compression. You can find out more about this at http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-image-compression

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* manipulate the **compressed data** directly to include your message, but you'd have to read up on how you're able to do it without totally corrupting the image.

But if you're thinking to encode the message in the **pixels** to do a per-pixel diff when decoding your message I'm afraid your assumption (from the comment on Daniel's answer) is wrong.

JPEG compression is lossy - this means that when you put the amended pixel data back into the image file it which will cause all pixel data to be lost (since it needs to be re-encoded.) Instead of pixel data the only information that's saved in the file is how to reassemble an image that appears very *similar looking* to the original for the human eye, but the pixel data is not the same.

Not even if you decode the image, then save it as a JPEG file, then do the transformation of the original image and finally save this as a second JPEG with the exact same compression settings can you rely on a per-pixel comparison.

However, as I seem to remember that JPEG compresses the image data in 8*8 pixel blocks, you might be able to manipulate and compare the image data on a per-block basis.

Answer (score 1):

> extract the pixel data (and nothing else) directly from the bytearray

To do this you need to decode the jpeg first (apart from some eventual metadata, there is nothing else than pixel data in a typical jpeg file), and the way to do that is precisely using Loader.loadBytes and then BitmapData.getPixels. You can probably make your own decoder (like the one you posted), but I don't see any benefit in doing so.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I don't want to use the Loader class, nor BitmapData.getPixels.  I know this is normally how one would go about it, but the project I'm working on doesn't allow it.  The decoder I posted uses a c++ library (LibJpeg) - which is out of my depth.

Comment: If you don't mind, why can't you use the Loader class? And regarding the decoder you posted, you can easily import the SWC file into your project and just use it (you don't need to do anything with the c library).

Comment: see my comment to LeeBurrows (above)

Answer (score 1):

A guy named Thibault Imbert at ByteArray.org adapted the libjpeg library for ActionScript 3. I have not tested this, but other folks seem to like it by the comments at bytearray.org.

http://code.google.com/p/as3-jpeg-decoder/downloads/list